# Trying to make UIImageView a circle and it appears twice

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to add an imageview as a circle in swift to a uiview.  I call the following code in swift however it creates the image to appear briefly incorrectly before it is corrected to a circle

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      theirPicMaskFour.layer.cornerRadius = theirPicMaskFour.frame.height / 2
      theirPicMaskFour.layer.masksToBounds = false
      theirPicMaskFour.layer.borderWidth = 0;
      theirPicMaskFour.clipsToBounds = true
  }
```

The following is the way it looks initially.
[image]

The following is how it looks after.
[image]

Comment: see  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31799451/5235106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
theirPicMaskFour.layer.cornerRadius = theirPicMaskFour.frame.size.width / 2
```

instead of

```
theirPicMaskFour.layer.cornerRadius = theirPicMaskFour.frame.height / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `theirPicMaskFour.layer.masksToBounds = true` and log out the height before u assign just to be sure that the height isn't something out of ordinary

[EDIT]
Alloc and init it in `viewDidLoad` but update the round rect in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as it will be called multiple times, but changes on frames wont effect it as that will remain same.

Comment: It is erroneous the the first time, didlayoutsubviews is being called twice...  how do I only get it to display on the screen the final autolayout constraints?

Comment: theirPicMaskFour is an outlet from the storyboard, the rounded rectangle is a view also from the storyboard, with a corner radius set...

Comment: Why dont u set the attributes in runtime in storyboard?